Tom-select ordering within optgroup
I am having an issue with tom-select, where the order of elements within an optgroup is not being preserved. Based on this docs, I thought that all I had to do was:
new TomSelect("#sampleSelect", {
  sortField:[{field:'$order'},{field:'$score'}],
  plugins: ['optgroup_columns'],
  lockOptgroupOrder: true,
});

But it is not working for me.
I am having a hard time making a minimal working example to reproduce this, so the snippet below contains the complete copy-pasted list of options I am using. Only cb01 optgroup is correctly sorted.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks


new TomSelect("#sampleSelect", {
  maxOptions: null,
  sortField:[{field:'$order'},{field:'$score'}],
  plugins: ['optgroup_columns'],
  lockOptgroupOrder: true,
});
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.3.1/dist/css/tom-select.bootstrap5.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>

<select
  class="form-select"
  placeholder="e.g. Option_A"
  id="sampleSelect"
>
  <option value="" selected=""></option>
  <optgroup label="cb01">
      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 0,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_0&quot;
}">p1_0</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 1,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_1&quot;
}">p1_1</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 2,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_2&quot;
}">p1_2</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 3,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_3&quot;
}">p1_3</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 4,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_4&quot;
}">p1_4</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 5,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_5&quot;
}">p1_5</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 6,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_6&quot;
}">p1_6</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 7,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_7&quot;
}">p1_7</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 8,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_8&quot;
}">p1_8</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 9,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_9&quot;
}">p1_9</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 10,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_10&quot;
}">p1_10</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 11,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_11&quot;
}">p1_11</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 12,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_12&quot;
}">p1_12</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 13,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_13&quot;
}">p1_13</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 14,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_14&quot;
}">p1_14</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 15,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_15&quot;
}">p1_15</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 16,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_0&quot;
}">p2_0</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 17,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_1&quot;
}">p2_1</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 18,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_2&quot;
}">p2_2</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 19,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_3&quot;
}">p2_3</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 20,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_4&quot;
}">p2_4</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 21,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_5&quot;
}">p2_5</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 22,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_6&quot;
}">p2_6</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 23,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_7&quot;
}">p2_7</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 24,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_8&quot;
}">p2_8</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 25,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_9&quot;
}">p2_9</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 26,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_10&quot;
}">p2_10</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 27,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_11&quot;
}">p2_11</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 28,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_12&quot;
}">p2_12</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 29,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_13&quot;
}">p2_13</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 30,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_14&quot;
}">p2_14</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 31,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_15&quot;
}">p2_15</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 32,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_0&quot;
}">lemo_0</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 33,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_1&quot;
}">lemo_1</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 34,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_2&quot;
}">lemo_2</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 35,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_3&quot;
}">lemo_3</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 36,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;cb01_lemo_4&quot;
}">cb01_lemo_4</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 37,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_5&quot;
}">lemo_5</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 38,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_6&quot;
}">lemo_6</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 39,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_7&quot;
}">lemo_7</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 59,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;sys_clock&quot;
}">sys_clock</option>
                      
                  </optgroup>
                  
                  <optgroup label="cb02">
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 0,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;MAG_0&quot;
}">MAG_0</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 1,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;BML_START_DUMP&quot;
}">BML_START_DUMP</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 2,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;BML_STOP_DUMP&quot;
}">BML_STOP_DUMP</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 3,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;BML_SEQ_RUNNING&quot;
}">BML_SEQ_RUNNING</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 4,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;RCT_BOTG_START_DUMP&quot;
}">RCT_BOTG_START_DUMP</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 5,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;RCT_BOTG_STOP_DUMP&quot;
}">RCT_BOTG_STOP_DUMP</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 6,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;RCT_BOTG_SEQ_RUNNING&quot;
}">RCT_BOTG_SEQ_RUNNING</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 7,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;ATM_BOTG_START_DUMP&quot;
}">ATM_BOTG_START_DUMP</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 8,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;ATM_BOTG_STOP_DUMP&quot;
}">ATM_BOTG_STOP_DUMP</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 9,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;ATM_BOTG_SEQ_RUNNING&quot;
}">ATM_BOTG_SEQ_RUNNING</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 10,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;MAG_1&quot;
}">MAG_1</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 11,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;MAG_2&quot;
}">MAG_2</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 12,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;MAG_3&quot;
}">MAG_3</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 13,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_13&quot;
}">p1_13</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 14,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_14&quot;
}">p1_14</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 15,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_15&quot;
}">p1_15</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 16,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_A&quot;
}">SiPM_A</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 17,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_H&quot;
}">SiPM_H</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 18,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_C&quot;
}">SiPM_C</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 19,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_D&quot;
}">SiPM_D</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 20,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_E&quot;
}">SiPM_E</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 21,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_F&quot;
}">SiPM_F</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 22,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_A_OR_D&quot;
}">SiPM_A_OR_D</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 23,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_C_OR_F&quot;
}">SiPM_C_OR_F</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 24,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;ADC_TRG&quot;
}">ADC_TRG</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 25,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_G&quot;
}">SiPM_G</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 26,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_B&quot;
}">SiPM_B</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 27,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_I&quot;
}">SiPM_I</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 28,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_J&quot;
}">SiPM_J</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 29,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_H_OR_I_OR_J&quot;
}">SiPM_H_OR_I_OR_J</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 30,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;MIC_SYNTH_STEP_START&quot;
}">MIC_SYNTH_STEP_START</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 31,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;MIC_SYNTH_STEP_STOP&quot;
}">MIC_SYNTH_STEP_STOP</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 32,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_0&quot;
}">lemo_0</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 33,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_1&quot;
}">lemo_1</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 34,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_2&quot;
}">lemo_2</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 35,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_3&quot;
}">lemo_3</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 36,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;cb02_lemo_4&quot;
}">cb02_lemo_4</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 37,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_5&quot;
}">lemo_5</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 38,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_6&quot;
}">lemo_6</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 39,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_7&quot;
}">lemo_7</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 59,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;sys_clock&quot;
}">sys_clock</option>
                      
                  </optgroup>
                  
                  <optgroup label="cb03">
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 0,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;10Mhz_CLK&quot;
}">10Mhz_CLK</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 1,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;AD_TRIG&quot;
}">AD_TRIG</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 2,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;CAT_START_DUMP&quot;
}">CAT_START_DUMP</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 3,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;CAT_STOP_DUMP&quot;
}">CAT_STOP_DUMP</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 4,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;CAT_SEQ_RUNNING&quot;
}">CAT_SEQ_RUNNING</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 5,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_5&quot;
}">p1_5</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 6,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;PMT_CATCH_OR&quot;
}">PMT_CATCH_OR</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 7,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;PMT_CATCH_AND&quot;
}">PMT_CATCH_AND</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 8,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_CATCH_OR&quot;
}">SiPM_CATCH_OR</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 9,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;SiPM_CATCH_AND&quot;
}">SiPM_CATCH_AND</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 10,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;POS_START_DUMP&quot;
}">POS_START_DUMP</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 11,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;POS_STOP_DUMP&quot;
}">POS_STOP_DUMP</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 12,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;POS_SEQ_RUNNING&quot;
}">POS_SEQ_RUNNING</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 13,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_13&quot;
}">p1_13</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 14,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_14&quot;
}">p1_14</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 15,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_15&quot;
}">p1_15</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 16,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_0&quot;
}">p2_0</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 17,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_1&quot;
}">p2_1</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 18,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_2&quot;
}">p2_2</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 19,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_3&quot;
}">p2_3</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 20,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_4&quot;
}">p2_4</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 21,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_5&quot;
}">p2_5</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 22,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_6&quot;
}">p2_6</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 23,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_7&quot;
}">p2_7</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 24,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_8&quot;
}">p2_8</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 25,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_9&quot;
}">p2_9</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 26,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_10&quot;
}">p2_10</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 27,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_11&quot;
}">p2_11</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 28,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_12&quot;
}">p2_12</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 29,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_13&quot;
}">p2_13</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 30,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_14&quot;
}">p2_14</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 31,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_15&quot;
}">p2_15</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 32,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_0&quot;
}">lemo_0</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 33,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_1&quot;
}">lemo_1</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 34,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_2&quot;
}">lemo_2</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 35,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_3&quot;
}">lemo_3</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 36,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;cb03_lemo_4&quot;
}">cb03_lemo_4</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 37,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_5&quot;
}">lemo_5</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 38,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_6&quot;
}">lemo_6</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 39,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_7&quot;
}">lemo_7</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 59,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;sys_clock&quot;
}">sys_clock</option>
                      
                  </optgroup>
                  
                  <optgroup label="cb04">
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 0,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_0&quot;
}">p1_0</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 1,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_1&quot;
}">p1_1</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 2,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_2&quot;
}">p1_2</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 3,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_3&quot;
}">p1_3</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 4,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_4&quot;
}">p1_4</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 5,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_5&quot;
}">p1_5</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 6,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_6&quot;
}">p1_6</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 7,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_7&quot;
}">p1_7</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 8,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_8&quot;
}">p1_8</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 9,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_9&quot;
}">p1_9</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 10,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_10&quot;
}">p1_10</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 11,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_11&quot;
}">p1_11</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 12,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_12&quot;
}">p1_12</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 13,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_13&quot;
}">p1_13</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 14,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_14&quot;
}">p1_14</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 15,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p1_15&quot;
}">p1_15</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 16,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_0&quot;
}">p2_0</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 17,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_1&quot;
}">p2_1</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 18,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_2&quot;
}">p2_2</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 19,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_3&quot;
}">p2_3</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 20,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_4&quot;
}">p2_4</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 21,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_5&quot;
}">p2_5</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 22,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_6&quot;
}">p2_6</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 23,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_7&quot;
}">p2_7</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 24,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_8&quot;
}">p2_8</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 25,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_9&quot;
}">p2_9</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 26,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_10&quot;
}">p2_10</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 27,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_11&quot;
}">p2_11</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 28,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_12&quot;
}">p2_12</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 29,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_13&quot;
}">p2_13</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 30,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_14&quot;
}">p2_14</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 31,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;p2_15&quot;
}">p2_15</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 32,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_0&quot;
}">lemo_0</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 33,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_1&quot;
}">lemo_1</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 34,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_2&quot;
}">lemo_2</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 35,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_3&quot;
}">lemo_3</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 36,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;cb04_lemo_4&quot;
}">cb04_lemo_4</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 37,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_5&quot;
}">lemo_5</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 38,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_6&quot;
}">lemo_6</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 39,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;lemo_7&quot;
}">lemo_7</option>
                      
                      <option value="{
  &quot;number&quot;: 59,
  &quot;description&quot;: &quot;sys_clock&quot;
}">sys_clock</option>
                      
                  </optgroup>
                  
                
</select>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.3.1/dist/js/tom-select.complete.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>



